# Server Side Image Sizing For Responsive Web Site

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need a good idea. I have a website with responsive design.

For example, I have a post and this post has a cover photo and :

- If the user's device is a mobile phone, I want to load this image like 300x300.
- If it's desktop device ==> 800x500
- If it's tablet ==> 600x400

The sizes are only examples. In reality, there are not only 3 sizes but 14 different sizes.

Now what should I do when uploading this image : Should I create 14 different sizes for one image ?

Holding 14 files for 1 image doesn't make sense to me. There should be a better way.

Do you have any better idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Popular approach to this problem is to generate multiple sizes of the same image dynamically. You can put the requested dimensions in the query string of the image URL, with potential size validation.

Often, these images are lazy-loaded, so the size is being generated the first time someone requests it.

Example:

```html
<img src="http://example.com/img/image.php?file=profile.jpg&size=400x400">
```

The `image.php` file would return the contents of existing scaled image file (if it exists) or generate it if it doesn't yet.

Comment: This. If you're looking for a way to easily do server-side image resizing, consider FFmpeg's scale filter with an added option to preserve the aspect ratio of the image by fitting or filling. (Make sure to validate the image file name as well; maybe just with a list of valid file names -- lots of exploits are often created with a shell call)

Comment: @Robo Robok I think that but there should be some performance problems maybe? Is that way fast?

Comment: The only problem is that the first user requesting an image will need to wait for scaling. It's not a huge deal though. Also, you can write a script to generate images non-lazily if you want to. There are many good solutions.

Comment: @RoboRobok like what?

Comment: You could just loop over desired sizes and images to generate all of them with some admin tool, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly, but by creating a separate layout for each device, you can determine how large the image should be for this device.

It could look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <body>
    <mobilephone>
        <style type="text/css">@media(min-width: 400px){smallheader{display: none;}}</style>
        <img src="Your Image">
    </mobilephone>
    <desktop>
        <style type="text/css">@media(max-width: 400px){smallheader{display: none;}}</style>
    </desktop>
</body>
</html>
```